# what the difference between MS Source Safe and Team Foundation Server?

Tags: version-control, tfs

MS solution for source code control is visual source safe before. Now MS advocate its TFS. What the difference between MS Source Safe and Team Foundation Server from functional perspective? And what's the difference between TFS and open source for source control, like subversion?

Comment: You'll get better answers at serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSS is source control, TFS is a full blown application lifecycle management tool encompassing work items, source control, build management, tests, lab, requirements management and document management (through SharePoint).

That is not to say that the source control management within TFS *is* VSS, it is not, its an entirely new source control product offered by Microsoft as part of the integrated ALM provided by Team Foundation.

Answer (score 4):

SourceSafe is going to finally disappear.  SourceSafe's closest relative will now be Team Foundation Server (TFS) Basic Edition BUT TFS is far more powerful and not frought with the issues SourceSafe had.

TFS has a lot more functionality than SourceSafe ever did.  TFS has Application Lifecycle Management (ALM), stored using SQL Server and many other features.

TFS Basic is a less feature rich version of TFS and can be installed in a few minutes with a wizard setup much like SourceSafe was.

Here's a link talking about [TFS Basic](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2009/10/01/tfs-2010-for-sourcesafe-users.aspx).

And here's a quote from the link:

> All of this gives you a development system with Version Control, Bug tracking and build automation (making continuous integration a snap!).  What it lacks from Standard TFS is Sharepoint and Reporting capabilities.  The great thing though is that TFS "Basic” IS TFS so as your needs grow you can reconfigure it to add more capabilities.

As compared to subversion... TFS is a version control system like subversion but again has all the other bells and whistles built in such as bug tracking and other ALM features.

Comment: Just for clarification, there is not a "Basic" version of TFS, just a "Basic" configuration.  There is only one version of TFS 2010, but the wizard allows for it to be configured in different ways.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  They originally called it in Beta "Basic Edition" but it is just a configuration of TFS :-)

Comment: No problem. :-) The basic configuration is quite nice, as I actually have it installed on both my laptops.  Have a nightly backup plan on my DBs and a nightly task to copy it to my Dropbox account.  Fairly lightweight, too, without SSRS and WSS.  I am hoping that the TFS Integration project on Codeplex reaches its ultimate goal of being able to use a "Basic" install for offline work.

Answer (score 2):

Team Foundation Server replaces SourceSafe.

In addition to source control, TFS also provides bug tracking and other project management features.